# multiple Facebook Send Buttons and titles not working + Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, addthis

I have a list of partials that each include a facebook send button from addthis.  The issue I'm running into is this: the facebook send button allows you to pass in a parameter for the url you want to show, but does its own look up of the title of the page you are currently on.  I would really like to specify the title of the facebook link that gets sent to whatever I want, rather than it looking at the title in the header of my layouts/application.html.erb file.  Each partial in this list is intended to have a unique title and a url to another page designated for that item solely.  I have two specific questions, and would also welcome any advice on this subject beyond the scope of these questions:

### Question 1:

Is it a bad idea, in general, to have more than one facebook send button on a page?  Due to the issue that I'm having, I've assumed that the intention was for this button to be used once per page so that the title lookup that it does makes a little more sense.  That way you'd just have to provide a title using a content_for helper for each page or something.  However, I still have a twitter button and an email button for each partial as well.  Is this too expensive (too much to load for a page, initially)?

### Question 2:

Would it be a bad idea to attempt to change the title of the page with every facebook send action just for the purpose of sending the correct title to someone on facebook?  I'm worried about things like SEO and things of that nature, but am sure that I'm leaving out other concerns as well.  Although, this is somewhat of an administrators page for managing these items one by one, and isn't really meant to be searchable by the general public.

I was hoping to get some advice on these questions in a general sense.  Thanks in advance!

### Update:

I was able to get it working by adding the following to the page that I was sharing, not the page I was currently on:

```
<% content_for :title do %>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<%= @f.g.name %> - <%= @f.title %>">
<% end %>
```

and adding the following to the application.html.erb layout view file:

```
<%= yield :title %>
```

Even though adding these meta tags happens on the fly, it happens before Facebook does it's scraping on the server for the title or open graph meta tag, so it works out.  Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Please let me know if I need to clarify anything for this one.  I'd really like to get some feedback on this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a bad idea, in general, to have more than one facebook send button on a page?

No, of course not.

> Would it be a bad idea to attempt to change the title of the page with every facebook send action just for the purpose of sending the correct title to someone on facebook?

You mean client-side? That does not work at all, because Facebook’s scraper will request the URL from your server to get the info.

You *can* pass your own values for title, description, image … when you use the Feed dialog or the old sharer.php) – but you will still get the info FB is able to extract from your document when a user shares a link manually.

You should really put appropriate Open Graph meta tags into your documents.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @CBroe!  So, when each partial specifies a unique url for the send button, does the title get scraped from the title that would appear in the case that the url being passed in is requested, and not the current url that I'm at?  Would it be sufficient to provide the Open Graph meta tags in the files for the html of the unique url's I'm passing in?  Sorry if this is a confusing question, but my page's title tag is specified in the overall application.html.erb file in the layouts directory.

Comment: I just realized that the meta tags most likely have to go in the header tag, so when I get the chance, I'm going to try to use a content_for rails helper for the title.  And I'm going to specify the title's content in the show.html.erb file for each of these objects being displayed in their partial form in my current page.  The show.html.erb page is the page that I'm passing the url in for the send button.  Does this sound right, if you have a chance to look at this again before I get home from work?

Comment: This approach worked for me.  I used content_for to add an open graph meta tag to the page that I was sharing, not the page I'm currently on.  Thanks for your help @CBroe